# Finding Deltas In Definite Integrals

Tags: calculus

At what $\delta$ does the relation $$\bigg|\int^\pi_0\sin x \, dx-\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\sin\alpha_i \Delta x_i\bigg|<0.001$$ follow from the inequality $\max \Delta x_i<\delta$

Comment: What are the $\alpha_k$ and the $x_k$ ?

Comment: It might help to split the integral up at $\pi/2$, so that you consider separate cases where the function is increasing and decreasing. Draw a picture and take all the $\Delta x_i$ to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^n$ is a partition of $[0,\pi]$, i.e.,
$$ x_0=0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_{i}<x_{i+1}<\cdots<x_n=\pi $$
and $\alpha_i\in[x_i,x_{i+1}], \Delta x_i=x_{i+1}-x_i, i=0,1,\cdots,n-1$. Using these, you can have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\bigg|\int^\pi_0\sin x \, dx-\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\sin\alpha_i \Delta x_i\bigg|\\
&=&\bigg|\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}(\sin x-\sin\alpha_i)\,dx\bigg|\\
&\le&\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}\bigg|2\cos(\frac{x+\alpha_i}{2})\sin(\frac{x-\alpha_i}{2})\bigg|\,dx\\
&\le&\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}\big|x-\alpha_i\big|\,dx\\
&\le&\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}\max \Delta x_i\,dx\\
&=&\max \Delta x_i\sum^{n-1}_{i=0}\int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}dx\\
&=&\max \Delta x_i \cdot\pi.
\end{eqnarray}
Letting
$$ \max \Delta x_i \cdot\pi<0.001 $$
you have
$$ \max \Delta x_i <\frac{1}{1000\pi} $$